# IIS Configuration. 1 Domain, multiple applications

Tags: iis, dns, configure

I'm having a bit of a problem here.
We have 2 urls let me call them http://www.testUrl.com/ and http://www.test-url.com/
This url points to a server using an "A-Record".

In IIS I've appointed these url's through "Advanced Website Identification" to the correct application. 
Now we have 2 apps. One application is version one the other is the more advanced application. 
Now my boss wants me to link one url to 2 different applications.
So when you surf to http://www.testurl.com/ or http://www.testurl.com you see the latest version but when you surf to http://www.testurl.com/folderinversion1/ you'll see the folder of the first application.

It's a though situation and I don't think there is a solution but I wanted to double check if you can assign 1 url to 2 applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just create a virtual directory called /folderinversion1 in the site for testurl.com pointing at the application root that is currently on the other site?